# SQL Server 2014 MARS error when using Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've altered one of my tables in the DB by adding two additional columns:

```
DeletedBy NVARCHAR(100)
DeletedOn DATETIME
```

The problem is that when I now either try adding or updating a row in the table I get the following error:

```
Procedure []: Error occured (207): Invalid column name 'DeletedBy'.\r\nA transaction that was started in a MARS batch is still active at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.
```

Dropping the columns from the DB fixes the issue. Any idea what may be causing this error? No other changes have been made other than adding the columns to the table.

I'm using EF 6

Comment: How did you alter the database and how did you update your model to reflect those changes?

Comment: ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN DeletedBy NVARCHAR(100)

Comment: I then deleted the table from the model and re-added it

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of things you can try.

- Disable MARS and try again: are you getting any error? Transaction
  rollback can mask the actual error. As I can see, the "DeletedBy" field is not nullable and looks like a strange thing: what are you going to write in that field when you are creating the record?
- Check [MARS, Transactions and SQL Error 3997, 3988 or 3983](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbiyikoglu/2006/11/20/mars-transactions-and-sql-error-3997-3988-or-3983/) by Cihan Biyikoglu.

Comment: The weird thing is that I left the previous .net logic exactly the same and it was working perfectly fine. All I did was add two additional columns to the table and not even using them in the code and I get this error

Comment: SQL Server will by default make those fields nullable though

Answer (score 0):

So after pulling out all of my hair I found out that the issue was actually caused by a trigger on the table I was updating. Disable the trigger and all is good. But none-the-less the error was quite cryptic.